# assert with error message equivalent in python

Tags: python, assert

Is there any pythonic way to write asserts with messages like in C/CPP:

```
assert(i <= j && "more participants than medals");
```

When I try the equivalent I get a pylint error which probably indicates there is a better way (?):

```
R1726: Boolean condition 'i <= j and "..."' may be simplified to 'i <= j' (simplifiable-condition)
```

Comment: [`assert` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement)

Comment: `assert i <= j , "more participants than medals"`

Comment: It just feels like you’ve randomly copied C++ code into Python without having even consulted the documentation. It’s arguably somewhat abstract, but if read carefully, that short paragraph in the docs explains exactly how to write a proper `assert` statement.

Comment: "emphasize that more than one expression can be tested, but the message itself is marginalized there" No, they don't; they show that exactly one or two expressions are permissible in the grammar; and then they show (by equivalent code) that the second expression, when provided, **is not** tested (but instead is the message to use).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python you should use this format:

```
assert <condition>,<error message>
```

So in your case it has to be like this:

```
assert i <= j,"more participants than medals"
```